# struct usb_device_id does not contain USB device information

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I am new to Linux kernel and I am presently learning USB device drivers.
I wrote a simple USB driver with probe callback and disconnect callback functions.

In the probe callback I try to display values of the struct usb_device_id argument passed to it. The problem is that structure variable shows product id and vendor id as 0.

What is the reason for this? Am I doing all right?

The code snippets from the driver are

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/usb.h>

int probe_callback(struct usb_interface *intf, const struct usb_device_id *id);
void disconnect_callback(struct usb_interface *intf);

struct usb_device_id usb_ids[]={
    {.driver_info=42},
    {}
};

struct usb_driver USB_DRIVER={
    .name="NEW USB",
    .id_table=usb_ids,
    .probe=probe_callback,
    .disconnect=disconnect_callback
};

//PROBLEM IS IN THE FUNCTION BELOW .....................

int probe_callback(struct usb_interface *intf, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "probe callback\n");
    __u16 vendor_id=id->idVendor;
    __u16 product_id=id->idProduct;
    printk("product id : %x vendor id : %x\n", product_id, vendor_id);
    return 0;
}

//..........................

void disconnect_callback(struct usb_interface *intf)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "disconnect callback\n");
}

static int start(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "module registered\n");
    int result;
    result=usb_register(&USB_DRIVER);
    if(result)
    {
            printk("error in registering usb driver...Error code = %d\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}

static void stop(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "module unregistered\n");
    usb_deregister(&USB_DRIVER);
}

module_init(start);  
module_exit(stop);
```

The logs I get when I execute dmesg are

```
[ 1539.714265] probe callback
[ 1539.714277] product id : 0 vendor id : 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `usb_id` table does not contain vendor and product IDs. The `id` pointer passed to your `probe_callback` points to the element of `usb_id` that matched the device being probed.

You need to fill in the elements of your `usb_id` table properly to match the devices you are interested in, for example using the `USB_DEVICE(vend, prod)` macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot....But can you suggest that how my driver will know the usb device info automatically without being specified by the programmer in the usb id table

Comment: @DebeshMohanty That would be a new question.